# “compute launch button tooltip” error in eclipse

Tags: ubuntu, java, eclipse, android

I'm trying to run Android SDK with Eclipse for the first time. I have never used Eclipse before and I'm running into the following error message over and over again, with no specific trigger: "compute launch button tooltip has encountered a problem"

I tried to Google it but I can't find a solution. It's driving me crazy, please help. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried re-installing Eclipse, same thing.

Comment: No attachment...

Comment: Can't, not enough repo. Just imagine an error message that pops out of nowhere from time to time with “compute launch button tooltip” @Xavierjazz

Comment: In your question you refer to a screenshot that is attached?

Comment: I wanted to, but it seems I can't. I tried to play with the eclipse a little, and found out that it probably has nothing to do with android sdk. When hitting 'details' in the error message, the following text is presented: An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModel @Xavierjazz

Answer (score 1):

[This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404216/elipse-run-as-does-not-display-the-list-elements-such-as-run-as-android-app) is similar and posts several answers. The most accepted answer is to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java
```

posted by [@pralabh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668676/pralabh) and also in [this post on Java Made Easy](http://javamadeasy.blogspot.com/2012/09/eclipse-run-asdebug-asprofile-as-doesnt.html).

According to [this blog](http://kausalmalladi.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/resolving-issues-with-eclipse-on-ubuntu.html) which has the same answer, this is an issue with the latest Ubuntu 12.04 LTS upgrade which was posted in a comment by [@kilaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435605/kilaka). That is certainly true for me, since eclipse has been working fine up to now.